# Identificar origem do código php

Tags: php, wordpress

Galera sei que a pergunta pode parecer simples ou algo do tipo, mas assim, as vezes desejo editar algo especifico na pagina feita no wordpress, e as vezes não sei onde é a origem daquela configuração entre os inúmeros arquivos php que o theme do wordpress que estou usando.

Tem como pelo inspecionar elemento indica em qual pasta ou lugar que posso encontrar nos arquivos php para poder editar ?

Por que estou estudando algumas funções e estou aprendendo como alguns themas funcionam e estou tentando aprender sobre os mesmos.

Desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Seguinte, eu acho que pelo inspetor difícil, porque é só html... Agora se pode e pegar um id especifico(se não for dinâmico) e através de um comando no sistema operacional, pesquisar arquivos que contenha o que vc procura..é uma ideia

Comment: É por que peguei tudo pronto e olhar 1 por 1 é complicado, achei que tinha alguma maneira fácil de achar, por que quando não é feito por nós é difícil saber onde fica cada coisa.

Comment: Veja se ajuda:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu7iK.png

Comment: Bom, eu não sei se entendi bem a sua pergunta. Você quer saber qual arquivo está editando? Pode ver o nome do arquivo pela URL, por exemplo.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Na verdade é assim, vou dar um exemplo... 

Faz de conta que estou na index da page e quero alterar uma informação ali, então pela logica ele fica no index.php 

Porem tem algumas paginas que tem algumas informações que não estou achando o arquivo de origem para poder editar.

Comment: Ah, você pode dar ctrl+shift+i na página que vai aparecer o html, o css, quais arquivos o css está, a opção pra ver a página responsiva e mais.

Answer (score 1):

Todos os temas seguem (ou deveriam seguir) a convenção do próprio Wordpress, descrita neste [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

por exemplo, se a página que você está vendo é um post, é bem provável que esteja no arquivo `single.php`, se for uma página, `page.php`

a imagem a seguir exibe a possibilidades de arquivos para este tipo de situação

[image: Hierarquia do template]

Lembrando que temas podem implementar as estruturas de formas diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Você deve inspecionar a página e encontrar a class de onde quer editar, esta class você deve pesquisar usando no "Adobe Dreamweaver", feito isso você vai encontrar em quais arquivos php está usando essa mesma class. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Importante você `EDITAR` esta pergunta, explicando-a de forma clara, objetiva e direta, enfatizando a dificuldade encontrada. Além disso, nos forneça um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, junto com sua tentativa de resolução. E mais, sugiro a leitura do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor o funcionamento da plataforma, evitando maiores frustrações.

Comment: Por favor, evite postar `imagens` de código nos seus posts - perguntas e/ou respostas. Para entender sobre os verdadeiros motivos leia [Manual de como NÃO fazer pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas).